# the visual basic development environment cannot provide multiple instances of a single use

Tags: vb6

I went over all articles but still I am not able to get rid of the error.
when I launch my desktop application it thrown below mentioned error.
"The visual basic development environment cannot provide multiple instances of a single use class. Consult the documentation for restrictions on debugging single -use objects"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe You are instancing an ActiveX EXE/DLL which has set the Property "Instancing" to "SingleUse". You can find this Property here:

[image]

As You haven't provided any source code nor any explanation what this ActiveX is doing, sadly I can't help You further. I can't merely suggest to You: "To avoid this error, just change the Instancing property to MultiUse" as this can have severe drawbacks for Your application. You will need to read the documentation about that property.

While for non-multithreaded EXE server implementing an object set to "single-use" instancing the situation is well defined, there are some more situations where using single-instancing objects can lead to unexpected results, even if single-instance objects have its own reason to be implemented.

> "When an EXE server component is implemented to provide multiple
>   single-use instanced objects, you will never know which server process
>   will actually be providing a particular object. So be carefully,
>   especially with regard to use of global variables in this situation."

(Credits: Dan Appleman)

Comment: Hi Deblocker, I dint change any code in the application. I tried to debug the exe(which is the single use com object) through vb6 IDI, I was able to hit the break point. later point of time, when I tried to launch the desktop application(the application which invoke this exe ), I got above mentioned error. Even I unregistered the exe and deleted all entries from registry and re-installed the desktop application. but still I can see same error.

Comment: @adadotnet: yes, I am aware, don't worry, it is a misunderstanding. Please, see my edit. Should read: *"I can't merely suggest You to change the Property "Instancing"*.

Comment: I am able to fix the issue by deleting single instance class entry from registry. Since I tried to debug this exe through VB6 IDE, it created one more instance of this class. it's working after deleting that entry from registry

Answer (score 2):

Creating multiple instances of a single-use class in an AX EXE requires multiple processes -- one for each instance. That can't happen in the IDE, which is inherently a single process. That's what the error is referring to.

Comment: Good explanation of what the error message actually means.